# Don't want to make application.xml file while making EAR file using ANT

Tags: ant, build, ear

I don't want to include or make application.xml in ear tag

How can i off this parameter

```
<ear earfile="${builddir}/myapp.ear"
appxml="ear_deploy_descriptor/application.xml"
basedir="${builddir}"
includes="*.jar,*.war"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see earTask documentation at http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ear.html.
If you specify **update="true"** then the **appxml** attribute is not required.

A Java EE 5 application is not required to provide an application.xml file in the EAR file.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to an issue with ANT when dealing with this. This was reported here: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51761

Try using the jar task instead of the ear and it should work.

```
<jar destfile="${builddir}/myapp.ear"
basedir="${builddir}"
includes="*.jar,*.war"/>
```